# automation of disable creating html report

Tags: sas

In the menu tools->options->preferences->results, is the checkbox tick "create html".
How can I disable this option in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using...

```
ODS HTML CLOSE;
```

...before you run you code.